# How to open xps document by clicking to link in another xps document

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm writing a help system for some application. This help system works with xps document. My program shows xps document with `documentviewer`. Xps document should link to another xps. When user will press to link `documentviewer` should show another xps document. I tried to use Google but I didn't find anything. Have you any idea how I can do that?

Comment: the link is inside the xps document, or you make it